# python GTK container for mjpeg stream

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, mjpeg

I have an mjpeg stream from a web-cam and would like to display it in an application written in python using pygtk. 
The stream is a string of bytes from the driver.
What widget would be best for displaying this and would I need to do some intermediate conversion before putting it in the widget? Should I write my own widget to do this?

Answer (score 2):

GTK+ does not contain a native widget capable of decoding and rendering video.

You should probably look into [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/), which is a streaming-media toolkit built on the same GObject framework as GTK+.

It has the [GstXvImageSink](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-xvimagesink.html) that is capable of rendering video using X11, and you should be able to configure it to render on top of a GTK+ widget.

Comment: The autovideosink might also be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

This example helped me getting started with gstreamer, it shows how one grabbs the webcam stream and displays it in an widget.

http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/webcam-viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use an Image widget to show the MJPEG stream.

Start a background thread, and have it read the stream and update the Image using `gtk.gdk.PixbufLoader` and `image_widget.set_from_pixbuf`

For example:

```
for frame in self.get_raw_frame():
    loader = gtk.gdk.PixbufLoader('jpeg')
    loader.write(frame)
    loader.close()
    pixbuf = loader.get_pixbuf()
    # Schedule image update to happen in main thread
    gobject.idle_add(self.widget.set_from_pixbuf, pixbuf)
```

Full working example is here: https://gist.github.com/mic159/fa2181a69f9119871b87